# uWSGI trying to load non-existing ini

Tags: uwsgi

so I have been trying to add a python app to uwsgi, but it was failing and I decided to redo (and also rename) the application. So I deleted old ini file from /etc/uwsgi/sites-available (lets call it 'example1.ini' and also the application directory from the server ('example1').

Then I uploaded a new directory (lets call it 'example2') and created a new ini file called 'example2.ini'. I also created a symlink.

Now when I try to restart uwsgi, it fails and when I see its status it is trying to load the old ini file (example1.ini) and it causes it to fail. In addition to that, it does not even load the new app.

Is there any way to reload all apps/remove cache/refresh the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I hope this helps someone. There was no obvious fix so I tried to reboot the whole server (computer) and it helped.